# React-router <Link> has no active class

Tags: react-router

I would like my `<Link>`s to have an `active` class when they match their route. Currently the resulting `<a>` tag doesn't change, even when I'm on the route referenced by the link.

My links are created like this: `<Link to="/status">STATUS</Link>`

The routes:

```
  <Router>
    <Route path='/' component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={Status} />
      <Route path='about' component={About}/>
      <Route path='status' component={Status}/>
      <Route path='settings' component={Settings}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
```

Does this feature even exist? If so, what do I need to change for it to work.

PS: I'm using react-router with redux-router. I also use the default HashHistory because it's a `nwjs`-app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `activeClassName` property to specify the class to add when the link is active.

```
<Link to="/status" activeClassName="active">STATUS</Link>
```

Comment: According to the API you should be right but it still doesn't work for me -.- Will try if an update helps.

Comment: Updating to react-router 2.0.0-rc5 fixed the issue, thanks.

Comment: Use `<NavLink />` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar problem with `react-router-dom` version 4.2.2. 
 Instead of the `Link` component, I was able to use the [NavLink](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink) component which includes the `activeClassName` prop.

From the documents:

> **NavLink**: A special version of the  that will add styling attributes to the rendered element when it matches the current URL.

*Here is a code sample*:

```
<ul className="menu col-sm-12">
  <li><NavLink to={`/events`} activeClassName="current">Events</NavLink></li>
</ul>
```

Note: `activeClassName` was removed from the `Link` component in React Router v4 ([relevant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41131450/active-link-with-react-router?rq=1)).