# Active link with React-Router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

I'm trying out React-Router (v4) and I'm having issues starting off the Nav to have one of the `Link`'s be `active`. If I click on any of the `Link` tags, then the active stuff starts working. However, I'd like for Home `Link` to be active as soon as the app starts since that is the component that loads at the `/` route. Is there any way to do this?

Here is my current code:

```
const Router = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      <Nav>
        <Link activeClassName='is-active' to='/'>Home</Link> {/* I want this to start off as active */}
        <Link activeClassName='is-active' to='/about'>About</Link>
      </Nav>

      <Match pattern='/' exactly component={Home} />
      <Match pattern='/about' exactly component={About} />
      <Miss component={NoMatch} />
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
)
```

Answer (score 273, accepted):

*This is an old, outdated answer for **React Router v4***

---

`<Link>` no longer has the `activeClassName` or `activeStyle` properties. In react-router v4 you have to use [`<NavLink>`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink) if you want to do conditional styling:

```
const Router = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      <Nav>
        <NavLink exact activeClassName='is-active' to='/'>Home</NavLink>
        <NavLink activeClassName='is-active' to='/about'>About</NavLink>
      </Nav>

      <Match pattern='/' exactly component={Home} />
      <Match pattern='/about' exactly component={About} />
      <Miss component={NoMatch} />
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
)
```

I added an exact property to the home `<NavLink>`, I'm fairly sure that without it, the home link would always be active since `/` would match `/about` and any other pages you have.

Comment: I overlooked this answer today because I thought using NavLink was avoiding the problem at first glance. It is hard to find anywhere else that explains this. People need to upvote this answer because he is exactly right. you have to use NavLink. ALSO! the exact={true} is exactly right too. Otherwise the first link that renders will not re render when you click other links causing home to always be active. I wish I could upvote you 10 more times.

Comment: In case of nested routes, you might need to use `exact` for the `NavLink` too.

Comment: Thank you for that link, @PetrAdam - was wondering why this wasn't working! (the solution is to wrap the `connect` call with `withRouter`).

Comment: To avoid redux blocking a re-render you can provide the option `pure: false` to the `connect()` method.
More information about a view no being updated: [https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md)

Comment: exact={true} on the home NavLink is a must, otherwise dashboard always stays active, very good explanation

Comment: exact={true} is needed for "/" route

Comment: Just wondering does this only work with BrowserRouter or even with Router

Comment: @jayarjo as far i know, it's still valid for react-router 4, which was the current version at the time. it might help to pull that information to the top of the answer?

Comment: the code snippet got edited to take advantage of the default "truthiness" of props; `exact` and `exact={true}` are equivalent

Answer (score 40):

**React Router v6:**

Source: [Active NavLink Classes with React Router](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/active-navlink-inline-styles-with-react-router)

Now you can use the `className` property which now accepts a function and passes an `isActive` boolean property, like this:

```
<NavLink
  to="users"
  className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? 'active' : 'inactive')}
>
  Users
</NavLink>
```

You can also adding multiple classes too, since **v6** is out:

```
<NavLink
  to="users"
  className={({ isActive }) =>
    isActive ? 'bg-green-500 font-bold' : 'bg-red-500 font-thin'
  }
>
  Users
</NavLink>
```

Live demo: [Active NavLink Classes with React Router](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/active-navlink-inline-styles-with-react-router)

Answer (score 13):

```
import { NavLink, useMatch, useResolvedPath } from 'react-router-dom';

const CustomNavLink = ({ to, title }) => {
   let resolved = useResolvedPath(to);
   let match = useMatch({ path: resolved.pathname, end: true });

   return (
      <NavLink to={to} className={`d-flex align-items-center py-2 px-4 ${match ? 'cta-btn' : 'c-n-b-link'}`} >
        <span className='ms-1 f-w-600'>{title}</span>
      </NavLink>
)
}
```

For `React router V6`The above custom component will return a navlink that an active class can be activated whenever the path matches the given `to` path.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! This component can also be used to resolve the "deep nested active" link problem :)

Comment: Have just realized `Navlink` has an active class `.active` so if you pass in your own class like `mynavlinkclass` and target `mynavlinkclass.active` you can style the link when its active. This is `Navlink` from `React router dom V6`

Comment: if you want the menu item (for example, `/example`) to be active on all nested urls (`/example/any/nested`) then `end` must be set to `false`.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by @Live Software Developer, in v6, I believe it's much simpler to do this (the typing below comes from TypeScript):

```
const CustomNavLink: React.FC<{ to: string; text: string }> = ({
  to,
  text,
}) => {
  return (
    <NavLink
      to={to}
      className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? "active" : "inactive")}
    >
      {text}
    </NavLink>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

***As an addition to @Nick's answer (React Router v6), for those who needs the active navigation state in the upper context..***

Conditional rendering might be a use case for the need. For ex: if it is active render the filled icon otherwise render the regular one.

This could be achieved by finding the route that we are currently in and then we can do the conditional rendering operation however it would be a little cumbersome.

Instead, we can write a function that modifies the state in `Navlink`'s style prop as following..

```
  const [active, setActive] = useState('home')

  const activate = (isActive, path, activeStyle, nonActiveStyle) => {
    if (isActive) {
      setActive(path)
      return activeStyle
    }
    return nonActiveStyle
  }

  return (
    <nav>
      <NavLink
        to="/"
        style={(activeNav) => activate(activeNav.isActive, 'home')}
      >
        {active === 'home' ? <HomeFill /> : <Home />}
      </NavLink>
      <NavLink
        to="/profile"
        style={(activeNav) => activate(activeNav.isActive, 'profile')}
      >
        {active === 'profile' ? <ProfileFilled /> : <Profile />}
      </NavLink>
    </nav>
  )
```

Comment: I respect that you want to enhance this but the code you provided has no explanation and does not really work. This would leave someone searching for an answer at an unwanted state. Maybe there is a way to improve your answer?

Answer (score 0):

In my case `<NavLink />` automatically set `active` class to items so I use the following method

***myComponet.js***

```
<ListItem component={NavLink} to="/somewhere" className="myactive" > something </ListItem>
```

***myStyle.css***

```
a.active.myactive {
 // some styles
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `react-router-dom Version 5.3.0` I have used the following to enable the active link

**classes:**

```
active: {
        // background: 'linear-gradient(180deg, #008b32 0%, #cddc39 100%)',
        // backgroundColor: 'slategray',
        borderBottom: '1px solid white',
        borderRadius: '6px',
        boxShadow: 'rgba(6, 24, 44, 0.4) 0px 0px 0px 2px , rgba(6, 24, 44, 0.65) 0px 4px 6px -1px , rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08) 0px 1px 0px inset',
        color: 'white',
        fontSize: '14px',
        listStyle: 'none',
        marginLeft: '16px',
        padding: '5px',
        textDecoration: 'none',
        textTransform: 'uppercase',
        transition: 'all 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.42, 0.02, 0.06, 0.05) 0.1s',
    },
    link: {
        '&:hover': {
            borderBottom: '1px solid white',
            borderRadius: '6px',
            boxShadow: 'rgba(6, 24, 44, 0.4) 0px 0px 0px 2px , rgba(6, 24, 44, 0.65) 0px 4px 6px -1px , rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08) 0px 1px 0px inset',
            color: 'white',
            padding: '5px',
            transition: 'all 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.42, 0.02, 0.06, 0.05) 0.1s',
        },
        color: '#ddf1f9',
        fontSize: '14px',
        listStyle: 'none',
        marginLeft: '16px',
        textDecoration: 'none',
        textTransform: 'uppercase'
    },
```

**NavLink.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";


const NavLinks = classes => {
    const pathname = useLocation().pathname
    return (
        <nav>
            <ul className={classes.navlinks}>
                <li>
                    <Link
                        className={`${pathname === '/' ? classes.active : classes.link}`}
                        to='/'
                    >
                        Login
                    </Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link
                        className={`${pathname === '/dashboard' ? classes.active : classes.link}`}
                        to='/dashboard'
                    >
                        Dashboard
                    </Link>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    )
}
```