# React Router NavLink Active

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I am new to react and react-router. I have a sidebar that has a route link
to store information details.

// Sidebar Link

`<NavLink to=“/store/information/details”>Information</NavLink>`

Inside store information details container has a button link route to edit store information that looks like this

// Link to Edit Information

`<NavLink to=“/store/information/edit”>Edit Information</NavLink>`

The problem is I want the sidebar link information to stay active when navigating
to edit store information container. When I am inside edit store information container the active class is removed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Active link with React-Router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41131450/active-link-with-react-router)

Comment: No. This is different use case.

Comment: You want to navigate to the second link and first to stay active? Right?

Comment: Yes i want the first to stay active

Comment: I read this docs in isActive prop but don't know to use https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink/isactive-func

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can write isActive of your Navlink like this:

```
 isActive={(match, location) => {
 return location.pathname.includes("/store/information/");
    }}
```

so your whole Navlink would be like this:

```
      <NavLink
    to="/store/information/details"
    activeClassName="active"
    isActive={(match, location) => {
      return location.pathname.includes("/store/information/");
    }}
  >
    information page
  </NavLink>
```

you can find a complete example in the code sandbox that I have provided for you:

https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-haze-13477

more resources:
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink/isactive-func

let me know if you still have any problem with it