# Highlight current page in bootstrap with react

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-router, react-bootstrap

I have seen multiple questions related to this and I have tried them all, with no results. So, posting yet another seemingly duplicate question.

I am trying to highlight the current page button in the navigation bar. For simple examples, where I am not routing it to a new page, it works. But when I route it to a different page (a separate react component) it doesn't work.

Here is the code I have:

**App.jsx**:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div>
                <Route exact={true} path='/' component={HomeApp}/>
                <Route path='/form' component={SomeForm}/>
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

**NavigationBar.jsx**

```
class NavigationBar extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        toggleIcon();
    }

    render() {
        return (<div id="topheader">
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light ">

            <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">Whatever</a>

            <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
                    aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul className="navbar-nav nav nav-pills ml-auto">
                    <li className="nav-item active">
                        <a className="nav-link" href="/">Home <span className="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li className="nav-item">
                        <a className="nav-link" href="/form">Submit Form</a>
                    </li>
                    <li className="nav-item">
                        <a className="nav-link" href="#">Sign Up</a>
                    </li>
                    <li className="nav-item">
                        <a className="nav-link " href="#">Login</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default NavigationBar
```

**navigation.js**

```
import $ from 'jquery';

export function toggleIcon() {
    $( '#topheader .navbar-nav a' ).on( 'click', function () {
        $( '#topheader .navbar-nav' ).find( 'li.active' ).removeClass( 'active' );
        $( this ).parent( 'li' ).addClass( 'active' );
    });
}
```

As seen, the highlighting works when I click `Sign Up` or `Login`, as they are not being routed to any other component.

But when I click on `Submit Form` which is routed to `SomeForm` component, the highlighting goes back to `Home` button.

For more details, I am posting the contents of `HomeApp` and `SomeForm` components:

**HomeApp.jsx**

```
class HomeApp extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <NavigationBar/>
                <Jumbotron/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default HomeApp
```

**SomeForm.jsx**

```
class SomeForm extends Component {
    render() {
        return (<>
                <div className="container">
                    <NavigationBar>
                    </NavigationBar>
                </div>
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default SomeForm
```

Comment: Since you are using react-router, why don't you use the <NavLink /> component instead of <a /> tags? After using that it has active link support out of the box already. You can take a look into this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41131450/active-link-with-react-router. You can also take a look into the following documentation: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/NavLink.md

Answer (score 4):

Please follow along this structure:

```js
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom"
```

```
class App extends React.Component{
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App">
          <Navigation />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
            <Route exact path="/contact" component={MoreRoutes} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}
```

And you need to use [NavLink](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink) as @Mikail Bayram mentioned, that will allow you to use [activeClassName](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink/activeclassname-string) also, the `exact` prop is required on each of your routes to have routes render only when the path is have the exact match. Please note that you can call the `active` class whatever you like.

Your Navigation should look like this:

```js
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom"
```

```
const Navigation = () => (
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <NavLink exact activeClassName="active" to="/">
          Home
        </NavLink>
      </li>
      <li>
        <NavLink exact activeClassName="active" to="/about">
          About
        </NavLink>
      </li>
      <li>
        <NavLink exact activeClassName="active" to="/contact">
          Contact
        </NavLink>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
)
```

As a side note: You should **Never** combining [jQuery with React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51304288/what-is-the-right-way-to-use-jquery-in-react)

Here is a live example at [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-ishizaka-hk0pi)

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to highlight parent element of link (li) you can use [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) (or [useLocation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/uselocation) hook for functional components) with [NavLink](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink) from react-router in NavigationBar:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

class NavigationBar extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.renderMenuLink = this.renderMenuLink.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        toggleIcon();
    }

    renderMenuLink({ path, label }) {
        const { location } = this.props;
        const isActive = location.pathname === path;
        return (
            <li key={path} className={`nav-item ${isActive ? 'active' : ''}`}>
                <NavLink className="nav-link" to={path}>
                     {label}{isActive ? <span className="sr-only">(current)</span> : ''}
                </NavLink>
            </li>
        );
    }

    render() {
        const menuLinks = [
            { path: '/', label: 'Home' },
            { path: '/form', label: 'Submit Form' },
            { path: '/register', label: 'Sign Up' },
            { path: '/login', label: 'Login' },
        ];
        return (<div id="topheader">
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light ">

            <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">Whatever</a>

            <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
                    aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul className="navbar-nav nav nav-pills ml-auto">
                    {menuLinks.map((menuLink) => this.renderMenuLink(menuLink))}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(NavigationBar);
```

Comment: Actually, in this case even [Link](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link) would be enough instead of NavLink, because you do not want formatting of active <a> element itself