# How to add activeClass in React

Tags: reactjs

I am newbie in React.
How to add activeClass on menu(`header`) ?

This is what I tried so far.

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Switch, BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import Header from './layouts/Header'; 
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import About from "./pages/About"; 

class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return (
      <Router>
        <Header/>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="content">
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
              <Route path="/about" component={About} /> 
            </Switch> 
          </div>
        </div> 
      </Router>
    )
  }
} 
export default App;
```

header.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

class Header extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return (
      <div className="header">
        <Link to="/" activeClassName='is-active'>
          Home
        </Link>
        <Link to="/about" activeClassName='is-active'>
          About
        </Link> 
      </div>
    )
  }
}
  
export default Header;
```

Comment: When you say `activeClass` are you asking how to add a style for the `active` state of your link?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41131450/active-link-with-react-router

Comment: @AhmetEmreKılınç  As your URL, Link has no loger activeClass property in react V4. So I changed to navLink. Thankyou works perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

You must use `NavLink` instead of `Link`, it has a prop that is exactly what you need `isActive`

Take a look at [doc](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink)

Comment: thank you. Lot of useful examples:)