# How to style active navigator item in the navbar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, navbar

I am working with Reactjs using html, css, and javascript.
I want to style active navigator item in the navbar with white border. That is mean the border will stay in the item while the page of this item is open.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./Navbar.css";
import { navItems } from "./NavItems";
import Dropdown from "./Dropdown";
    
function Navbar() {
  const [dropdown, setDropdown] = useState(false);


  return (
    <>
      <nav className="navbar">
        <ul className="nav-items">
          {navItems.map((item) => {
            if (item.id === "C3") {
              return (
                <li
                  key={item.id}
                  className={item.cName}
                  id={window.location.pathname === item.path? "C10":""}
                  onMouseClick={() => setDropdown(true)}
                  onMouseEnter={() => setDropdown(true)}
                  onMouseLeave={() => setDropdown(false)}
                >
                  <Link to={item.title}>{item.title}</Link>
                  {dropdown && <Dropdown />}
                </li>
              );
            }
            return (
              <li key={item.id} 
              className={item.cName}
              id={window.location.pathname === item.path? "C10":""}
              >
              
                <Link to={item.path}>{item.title}</Link>
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>

      </nav>
    </>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

This is the CSS file

```
  
.nav-item a:hover {
    border: solid 2px white;
  }


#C10{
  border: solid 2px white;
}
```

I try to use this method in CSS file.

```
.nav-item a:active {
    border: solid 2px white;
  }
```

and I use this method in CSS file and JS file also but it does not work!

```
id={window.location.pathname === item.path? "C10":""}
#C10{
  border: solid 2px white;
}
```

Comment: check your browser console, is <li> tag with id="C10" successfully rendered?

Comment: `a:active` is only for when an element is clicked and not for when a page is active

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Active link with React-Router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41131450/active-link-with-react-router)

Comment: id={window.location.pathname === item.path? "C10":""}
#C10{
  border: solid 2px white;
} This method does not work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to style an active `<Link/>` you have to use a `<Navlink/>` instead.

Check the doc: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/nav-link

Answer (score 0):

As William said you are better off using the actual `<NavLink/>` elements then programming plain html in React. However you can also create a function that adds the active class to the `li` item when it's selected.

See this example:

```
const links = ['https://google.com', 'https://google.be', 'https://google.nl'];
const [active, setActive] = useState(null);

<ul>
  {links.map((link) => (
    <li className="nav-item">
      <a 
        href={`#${link}`} 
        className={`nav-link ${active == link && 'm-active'}`}
        onClick={() => setActive(link)}
      >{link}</a>
    </li>
  ))}
</ul>
```